# ASP.NET Core delete image blob from azure & from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I have an ASP.NET application that successfully upload images to an azure container. I am trying to create a function that deletes a specific image in the blob, and delete the image from the database. Deleting it from the database isn't difficult, but attempting to delete it from azure throws an exception. I've scoured the web for an answer, but nothing! Anything helps! Below is the code:

> Error Exception

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(string connectionString)
```

> InterfaceService.cs

```
 public CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(string azureCString, string containerName)
    {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureCString);
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    }
```

> Products.cs

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var product = await _context.Product
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(product);
    }


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id, IFormFile file)
    {
        var product = await _context.Product.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        var container = _interfaceService.GetBlobContainer(AzureCString, "azureCstring");
        var content = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        var fileName = content.FileName.Trim('"');
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();

        _context.Product.Remove(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

Comment: an exception?  care to elaborate?

Comment: I've added additional details

Comment: this could be something with your secret manager if you are using a secret manager

Comment: I wish that would be the case, but I am not using secret manager.

Comment: It appears your connection string is null

Comment: That is what the error is telling me, but looks like my connection string isn't the issue. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you stepped through the GetBlobContainer method and verified that your string is present? My guess is it is being supplied null.

Comment: According to the exception, it seems that you connection string is null. You  could use the conection string with hard code in the GetBlobContainer function and test it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exception, it seems that you connection string is null. You could use the conection string with hard code in the GetBlobContainer function and test it again.

Based on my understanding you need to change the code `var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureCString);` to  `var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureCString);` in the GetBlobContainer function.

```
public CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(string azureCString, string containerName)
    {
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureCString); // change AzureCString to azureCString
        var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    }
```

Also make sure that `AzureCString` is not null in the **DeleteConfirmed** function. As I mentioned that you could use the hard code connection string. It should work.

Comment: Update:
So I've taken your advice and proceeded to hard code the connection string. After stepping through my code, the code is no longer null. But, a new exception occurred:
"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

It is referencing the "var content = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);" Any clue?

Comment: According to you mentioned error, it means that `file` is null so please check file object during debug.

Comment: Thank you Tom for that answer. You are right about the file being null. I still didn't manage to fix the issue. Thanks anyway.